# Any reason for a react state hook set callback to fire twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, callback, react-hooks

I have this simple code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('something', data => {
    console.log('ONE');

    setState(old => {
      console.log('TWO');

      const newArr = [...old];

      // do something to newArr
      return newArr;
    });
  });

  return () => {
    socket.off('something');
  };
}, []);
```

Everything works as intended but for some reason the `something` callback triggers once (the `ONE` is printed once), but inside when I set the state, the `setState` callback is called twice (it prints `TWO` twice). Why is that?

Comment: This is done [on purpose](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) in development mode.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, oh i see, so... how do i avoid it?

Comment: You don't. In production mode it won't do that, and in development mode, it's done to quickly reveal issues if you perform mutations or store state externally to react hooks. In short, nothing's wrong and nothing needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### This is a feature of React's [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode) (no, it's not a bug).

The `setState()` updater function, [among other methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), is invoked twice in a strict context during development mode only in order to quickly reveal common antipatterns, including state mutations and externally managed state.

These efforts are in preparation for the upcoming [concurrent mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro), which is expected to regularly invoke these methods multiple times per render as the internal implementation of react's render phase grows more complex.

In short, nothing needs to be fixed. React is just making it easier for you to discover logic errors in development while staying performant in production.